# @fopen in PHP does not support relative URLs

Tags: php, url, fopen, relative-path

Why does PHP not support relative URLs?

Can this be done with other programming languages? That the the server side can micro quick detect?

```
$urla="http://cdn.domain.net";
$urlb="//cdn.domain.net";

if(@fopen($urla,"r")){
// I work
}

if(@fopen($urlb,"r")){
// I do not work
}
```

Now that I mention it, much of the prime PHP cannot work like this or does not support as I am guessing due to server side - perhaps modification of CORE PHP is need in the C libraries? ([What is a Relative URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http))

Comment: One can dream can't he.. although this is micro issue.. it would help me too.. you need to modify C files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does PHP not support relative URLs?

Relative URL support needs a Base URL the relative URL is relative to. Please see [*4.2.  Relative Reference* in RFC 3986 URI Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2).

Taken that into account, there is a PHP Library available that actually does support relative URLs and it is compatible with `fopen`. It's called [`Net_URL2`](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/):

```
require_once('Net/URL2.php'); # or configure your autoloader

$baseUrl = 'http://cdn.domain.net';

$hrefRelativeOrAbsolute = '//cdn.domain.net';

$baseUrl = new Net_URL2($baseUrl);

$urlAbsolute = (string) $baseUrl->resolve($hrefRelativeOrAbsolute);
```

See as well [problem with adding root path using php domdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442292/problem-with-adding-root-path-using-php-domdocument).

Comment: @Quentin answer the question. You provided a solution for it. Repped you both. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does PHP not support relative URLs?

Because it doesn't have a base URL to be relative from (although one *could* be calculated from the request URI … but only for PHP scripts triggered by an HTTP request).

… and if it supported relative URIs in `fopen` then it couldn't support relative file paths as they couldn't be differentiated.

Comment: I disagree with your disagreement

Comment: Quentin is right in his statement, protocol relative urls only work in browsers. (you even have problems in html mails... at least outlook dont know what todo with it and thinks its a network path.)

Comment: @Rufinus — Email is generally fetched over IMAP, POP or Exchange, not HTTP or HTTPS, so a scheme relative URI wouldn't make sense there.

Comment: quentin... you do know what HTML mail mean, don't you :-)

Comment: @Rufinus — A bundle of content using the text/html MIME type (or, hopefully, a multipart MIME message that includes text/html with a text/plain alternative) that is delivered over SMTP to the recipient's mail server from which they fetch it using IMAP, POP3, Microsoft's proprietary Exchange protocol or whatever Lotus did with Notes and Domino. (They might also use a webmail service (in which case they would be using HTTP(s)), but not if they are using Outlook).

Comment: @Quentin nice answer, but i think you know perfectly what i meant by html mail and i stated outlook to (so no webmail interface). I give you one for the effort, to put your foot in it, and trying get out of it :-)

Comment: @Rufinus — It was because you mentioned outlook (and not webmail) that I pointed out why a scheme relative URI wouldn't make sense in the first place. While I think that treating it as a network path *is* a bug, I don't see what treatment would make them useful in an email.

Answer (score 0):

Indication of the protocol in the url for this function required, it is a language construct indicating a wrapper unlike example in your link.

Why it's needed and how to use can be found in the php documentation [php wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)

Comment: Where does it tell you why it is needed? I can't see it in the main content. Is it in one of the many user contributions on the page? A direct link to the relevant one would be appreciated.

Comment: It is understandable on the logic of functions. filesystem functions such as fopen (), copy (), file_exists () and filesize () call wrapper for doing some, it cant work without wrapper.