# How to get string before "words" or after "words" in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, xpath

I need help to get the value `#4bbedd` from `style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;"` using `PHP` functions if there is `xPath` for this then thanks i needed to 
and here is the `HTML` code for this

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pickerContainer" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1">
        <div class="ColorPicker" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0">
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue.0">Aquatic Blue</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Ash">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Ash.0">Ash</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Ash.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#999999;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Athletic Heather">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Athletic Heather.0">Athletic Heather</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Athletic Heather.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#F27EB2;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea.0">Azalea</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#000000;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Black">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Black.0">Black</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Black.1"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide examples of what you've already tried, rather than asking for a solution straight out the door.

Comment: try using `preg_match`.

Comment: i have tried this `substring-before(substring-after((//div/div[@class="ColorPicker"]/a/@style, "background-color: "), ";")')`

Comment: @MnthnSatani what was the problem using that XPath?

Comment: XPath is working but there is no results if i use `substring-before(substring-after((XPath/@style, "background-color: "), ";")')` with xpath

Comment: How did you execute that XPath? What was the function you used?

Comment: I execute XPath in chrome and this functions are i found in this site in another question

Comment: I have tried this `$e.outerHTML.substring($e.outerHTMLsubstring(';vertical',76).lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)` in PHP and in this $e is contain xpath result for `<a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue">` this means `$e.outerHTML` contains the value or it is the variable

Comment: The XPath in your first comment should work if you run it using `DOMXPath::evaluate()` : [XPath Substring-After Help / Query/Evaluate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450323/xpath-substring-after-help-query-evaluate/30476787#30476787)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/766255)

```
<?php

$object = new DOMDocument();
$object->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pickerContainer" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1">
        <div class="ColorPicker" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0">
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#4bbedd;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue.0">Aquatic Blue</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Aquatic Blue.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Ash">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Ash.0">Ash</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Ash.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#999999;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Athletic Heather">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Athletic Heather.0">Athletic Heather</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Athletic Heather.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#F27EB2;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea.0">Azalea</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Azalea.1"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui small interactive circular label" style="background-color:#000000;vertical-align:middle;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Black">
                <span class="toolTip" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Black.0">Black</span>
                <i class="checkmark icon" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.3.0.0.1.1.1.1.0.$Black.1"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>');
$xPathObject= new DOMXPath($object);
$result=$xPathObject->query("/html/body/div/div/a[1]");
$desiredResult="";
foreach($result as $data)
{
    foreach($data->attributes as $attribute)
    {
        if($attribute->name=="style")
        {
            $desiredResult= explode(";",explode(":", $attribute->value)[1])[0];
        }
    }
}
echo $desiredResult;
```